# Difference between DOM update and re-render

Tags: reactjs

We often hear about two phases, DOM update and re-render, in React. We know, React uses reconciliation and diffing algorithm to update the DOM. Again, if a state changes, react re-render the component and child component(if the memo is not used). So what is the basic difference between these DOM updates and re-rendering?

Comment: re-render is a process of Dom updation

Answer (score 3):

Re-rendering a component could not produce any DOM changes. React updates DOM only if the render process produces changes.

For example, you could have a component that is making an API request every minute (imagine it returns an object with some user data). When the API result comes, you could update some internal component state (calling setState with the API result) that will produce a re-render. But if nothing in the resulting virtual DOM tree changes (because nothing in the user data has changed), nothing in the DOM will be updated.

Comment: So, why there is a term called "costly re-render" if there is no change(let's say no user changes in the API call but there is a huge number of users)? Is it because it's going through getting all the values again and blocking the main thread?

Comment: That's right. If the component tree is large or the render functions do many calculations, the re-render will be slow. This can be avoided with memoization and other optimizations.